# Sync Problems with Chrome passwords and OSX keychain

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, osx-yosemite

After synchronizing my Keychain with iCloud and a power outage, I started experiencing some issues with the chrome password synchronization. I know passwords are still there in the [Google cloud](https://passwords.google.com/settings/passwords) but they are not being downloaded and used by form autocomplete even though is still enabled in the configuration.

[image: password configuration]

[image: password dialog]

I tried deleting my login keychain entry and restarting chrome but no luck. Is there a way to prevent Chrome from using the OSX system keychain as local password storage? I just need my passwords to be auto filled and synchronised with Google cloud.

OSX 10.10.5
Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 45, [Chrome no longer uses the OSX Keychain manager](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=466638). It may migrate passwords from Keychain into its own password manager.

> You can go to chrome://version/ and find a path to the profile. In the directory there is a 'Preferences'. Find 'keychain_migration' preference. The value can be one of
>
> ```
> // Migration wasn't tried yet.
> NOT_STARTED = 0,
>
> // Migration finished successfully.
> MIGRATED = 1,
>
> // Migration failed once. It should be tried again.
> FAILED_ONCE = 2,
>
> // Migration failed twice. It should not be tried again.
> FAILED_TWICE = 3,
> ```
>
> From 2 or 3 you can set it to 0 and restart the browser to try again.

Source: [Comment 45](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=466638#c45)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to chime in and say that I had this same issue just now and could not figure out for the life of me how to fix it.

I did eventually fix the issue by removing the **Chrome.app** from my **Applications folder**, deleting the **Google folder** from `~/Library/Google`, and removing the **Google folder** from `~/Library/Application Support/`.

Once I did all of that, I restarted my computer.

Next I redownloaded Chrome using Safari.  After reinstalling Chrome and signing in, everything synced (*including the passwords*).

Comment: **NOTE**: _Please_ do NOT attempt this if you want to preserve omnibar suggestions, autofill or search history saved on local machine (unless it is synced like bookmarks and passwords), this will delete all cookies and log you out of all websites. make sure you backup your Chrome User Data folder and paste it back after reinstall in order to get it all back.